In the figure if calculate the $DM$ segment
In the figure if $AB = 3$m and $BC = 2m$
Calculate $DM$.(M is point of tangency)
(Answer: $5\sqrt6$)

I try:
$DM^2 = DC(DC+5) = DC^2+5DC$(I)
$DC.(DC+5) = DF.(DF+2R) \implies DC^2+5DC = DF^2+2DF.R(II)$
$(I)=(II): DM^2 = DF^2+2DF.R$
$(2R)^2 = AE^2+AF^2 = CE^2+CF^2 = 4R^2$
$AF.CE =5.2R+AE.CF$

I have seen people getting their question downvoted and closed for way less.

@peta arantes, Is DM tangent to the semi circle?

@sirous..yes, DM is tangent

Claim: $MBH$ are collinear. 
Proof: Let $M'$ be the other tangent from $D$ to the circle. Clearly, $MM'$ is perpendicular to $EF$, so if we show $MM'$ passes through $AF \cap CE$, we will be done, as that would imply line $MM'$ coincides with line $BH$. 
This follows from a well-known lemma at the end of the answer. $\blacksquare$
Now, note that $AMCM'$ is a harmonic quadrilateral, where $B$ is the intersection of the diagonals. Let $\overline{DC} = x$. Then it is known that (unsigned lengths)
$$\frac{\overline{DC}}{\overline{DA}} = \frac{\overline{BC}}{\overline{BA}}$$
(or in other words, $B,D$ are harmonic conjugates of $A,C$)
Solving for $x$, we get $x = 10$m.
Now, finish by using the power of point $D$, $DM = \sqrt{DC\cdot DA} = \boxed{5\sqrt{6}}$.

Lemma: Let $D$ be an arbitrary point outside a circle, and let $DM$ and $DM'$ be tangents to it. Let $S,T,U,V$ be points on the circle such that $D,U,V$ and $D,S,T$ are collinear. 
Let $X= UT \cap VS$ and $Y = US \cap VT$. Then $M,M',X,Y$ are collinear.
Proof: Let $G = XY \cap UV$, $H = XY \cap ST$. Note that
$$(U,V;G,D) \overset{X}{=} (T,S; H,D)  \overset{Y}{=} (V, U; G,D) = k$$
which implies $k = -1$. (If you are not familiar with projections, I believe a straightforward Ceva-Menelaus will do the trick too). 
However, $UMVM'$ is a harmonic quadrilateral, so $-1 = (U,V; M',M) \overset{M}{=} (U,V;MM'\cap UV, D)$. (This is just using the property mentioned in the link above).
This gives $G$ lies on $MM'$, and similarly, $H$ lies on $MM'$. Hence $M,M',X,Y$ are collinear. $\blacksquare$
